# PEP 8 warning "Do not use a lambda expression use a def" for a defaultdict lambda expression

Tags: python, lambda, defaultdict

I am using the below python code to create a dictionary.But I am getting one **PEP 8** warning for the **dct_structure** variable. Warning is: `do not use a lambda expression use a def`

```
from collections import defaultdict

dct_structure = lambda: defaultdict(dct_structure)
dct = dct_structure()
dct['protocol']['tcp'] = 'reliable'
dct['protocol']['udp'] = 'unreliable'
```

I am not comfortable with python lambda expression yet. So can anyone help me to define the function for the below two line of python code to avoid the PEP warning.

```
dct_structure = lambda: defaultdict(dct_structure)
dct = dct_structure()
```

Comment: Do you ever actually call `dct_structure` again? What's `f`?

Comment: I made a mistake while copy pasting my code. I fixed that. Thanks, @jonrsharpe. for mentioning

Comment: @Arijit that's the standard way to define a nested `defaultdict`... What tool is causing the warning (if it hasn't already vanished by using the correct name)? You should have an option be it via command line arguments or by a comment of a specified format on the line itself to suppress that particular case.

Comment: @JonClements - I am using **Pycharm** for writing the code and it's still showing the warning.

Comment: @Erwin - I believe that this question is different than the other one. This is for lambda defaultdict expression.

Comment: @arjit - Fair enough, it is your question in the end. Though, the answer you accepted here is the same as the linked question... ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A lambda in Python is essentially an anonymous function with awkward restricted syntax; the warning is just saying that, given that you are assigning it straight to a variable - thus giving the lambda a name -, you could just use a `def`, which has clearer syntax and bakes the function name in the function object, which gives better diagnostics.

You may rewrite your snippet as

```
def dct_structure():
    return defaultdict(dct_structure) 

dct = dct_structure()
```