# def inside if/else ternary expression

Tags: python, conditional-operator

Is there a way to convert this:

```
if counts:
    def a(l):
        return a_with_counts(l)
else:
    def a(l):
        return a_without_counts(l)
```

into a ternary expression?

I tried something like this

```
def a(l):
    return a_with_counts(l) if counts else a_without_counts(l)
```

but I do not want the `if counts` to be evaluated each time I call `a(l)`, I want to do it once in the beginning of my method and then evaluate directly the assigned function each time I call `a(l)`. Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want the _ternary expression_ ?

Comment: why not add `counts` as a parameter to the function `def a(l, counts=True):` etc.

Comment: @B001ᛦ, because, for a given input, I will have to run that method many times and `counts` remains constant.

Comment: @Chris_Rands I don't want to evaluate `counts` each time. For a given input I want to do it once, and then use the assigned function throughout :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could achieve that by defining a closure as follows:

```
def gen_a(counts):
    return a_with_counts if counts else a_without_counts

a = gen_a(counts)
```

This is equivalent to writing

```
a = a_with_counts if counts else a_without_counts
```

if you only intend to call this once.

Comment: Aha! Thank you, this is exactly what I need. I have to admit this wouldn't have crossed my mind!

Answer (score 3):

with a ternary in a `lambda` ?

```
a = lambda counts:a_with_counts if counts else a_without_counts
```

then

```
a(True)   # or False
```

will create `a_with_counts` (resp `a_without_counts`) function that you can call.

Comment: you don't need a lambda to do this ... `a = (a_with_counts if counts else a_without_counts)(*args)`

Comment: Named lambdas :S

Comment: Do note the Python [PEP 8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations]) *Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier.*

Comment: @Parfait interesting. lambda are designed to remain anonymous. The sole interest here is to one-line define them. But jhansen answer (that I upvoted BTW) does that with a simple function.

Comment: @Skandix OP doesn't want to evaluate `counts` every time

Comment: damn I feel guilty about the `lambda` now because of you :)

Comment: I wasn't aware that you weren't aware they go against PEP8, thought you'd get my reference :) I'm not sure exactly what situation it avoids other than obscurity

Comment: well, I have some dark areas :) PEP talks about confusing tracebacks... thanks for your comments. duly noted. _must not use lambda, must not use lambda_

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: ok, leave it with `a_gen = a_with_counts if counts else a_without_counts`, without the call. still no lambda needed (meanwhile this is jhansen's answer)

Comment: It has been well mentioned on StackOverflow: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25010243/1422451), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45790434/1422451), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50091199/1422451)

Comment: damn I have read only 85% of the posts. Guess those ones went below the radar.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, thanks I tried that, but ran into the same PEP warning :) Although it did not cross my mind that I can assign a name to the output of a(True) and use that afterwards :)